# How to setup server side pre-receive hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I am new to git hooks and server side git functionality. I worked on client side git to commit and push my code and we do git merge using **Application Lifecycle management(ALM) tools**.
I am trying to write git hooks to do some testing on new/modified files in the repository. I am able to write and test client side hooks like **`pre-commit`**

Now, I need to add some server side git hook to verify files before merging to master because there is a change to skip client side verification using **`-no-verify`** option. When I go through some git hook tutorials, **`pre-push`** hook is the server side hook. I tried to create pre-push hook and it is working on client side. Now, How can make it as a server side hook and force to verify files when user try to push changes even with **`--no-verify`** option(should not be controled on client).

**My big question is how server hook is triggered when we do `git push` from local branch/repo.**

**Creation of hook:**

Created a hook called pre-commit and placed it under some folder **`git_hooks/pre-push`** and also in **`.git/hooks/pre-push`**. Now, created a symbolic link for my pre-push script. So, whenever I do **`git push`** it will trigger .git/hooks/pre-push which is a symbolic link for my script **`git_hooks/pre-push`**

**EDIT:**

I thought `pre-push` and `pre-receive` hooks are same as both are triggered on `git push` command but `pre-push` is working only client side, `pre-recieve` is working on server side.
I  created `pre-receive` hook and pushed it to master branch. Now, when I do `git push` getting this  **error: cannot spawn hooks/pre-receive: No such file or directory**.

I am trying this on both **Windows** and **Linux** platforms. On Windows I am getting this error, On Linux it is not even getting triggered. I placed `pre-receive` hook on master branch on both the platforms.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: **@for people looking for answer :**  **error: cannot spawn hooks/pre-receive: No such file or directory**. The reason for this error was  wrong SHEBANG. I modified it and I am not getting any error and pre-receive hook is working fine.                                                  We should place `pre-receive` hook in server .git/hook folder then whenever you try to push your changes server will trigger this hook. No need to have this on local repo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should look into [Server side hooks](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks#server-side-hooks) documentation section.

> There are three hooks that let you react to different stages of the git push process.

- pre-receive
- update
- post-receive

When you push to server `pre-receive` hook is triggered. Then for each branch you have pushed the `update` hook is triggered. When these hooks are finished without errors your patches are applied and `post-receive` hook is triggered

More detailed [DOC](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive) about `pre-receive` hook:

> This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack when it reacts to git push and updates reference(s) in its repository. Just before starting to update refs on the remote repository, the pre-receive hook is invoked. Its exit status determines the success or failure of the update.

**UPD**

To setup `pre-receive` server side hook you **should place script into `.git/hooks` directory on the server**. and name it `pre-receive`. That is all.
You should not create `hooks` directory at your repo and commit it. The `pre-receive` script is outside of repo

**UPD**
Here is example script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash


# check each branch being pushed

echo "pre-receive HOOK"

while read old_sha new_sha refname
do

if git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -qE '^\+(<<<<<<<|>>>>>>>)'; then
    echo "Saw a conflict marker in $(basename "$refname")."
    git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -nE '^\+(<<<<<<<|>>>>>>>)'
    exit 1
fi

if git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -qE '^\+.*\s+$'; then
    echo "Saw whitespaces at EOL."
    git diff "$old_sha" "$new_sha" | grep -nE '^\+.*\s+$'
    exit 1
fi

done

exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought pre-push and pre-receive are same but both are different . pre-push is also triggered for `git push` but only client side. I have created `pre-receive` hook but I am getting **error: cannot spawn hooks/pre-receive: No such file or directory**.

Comment: @Rekha:  I have updated answer. You just put `pre-receive` script on the server into `.git/hooks` directory. That is all. How to make this script to works properly is different question.

Comment: yes. I added that also. **hooks/pre-receive: No such file or directory** this represents .git/hooks only. File is there but still showing such error. I am not able to figure it out.  Some how it is triggering the event but not working properly.

Comment: @Rekha:  I suppose you use `pre-push` as `pre-receive`. You can not do that. Look at my script.

Comment: I do not have problem with script. I just have simple print statement. First hook should work properly then I can have any type of script based on my requirement right?

Comment: @ Eugen Konkov Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rekha: The script have 3 parameters: `old_sha` `new_sha` `refname`. You can do anything you want. One requirement is only exit status. When script exits with zero status `push` is applied. When non zero status - `push` is not applied and error reported to client.

Comment: @ Eugen Konkov Can you just do one more favor for me ? Server repository is on linux platform. How can we put hook in .git/hooks folder as I can not source control the hidden files ?

Comment: @Rekha: You `ssh` to server with your repository and put required file into `.git/hooks` folder in same way as you do that locally. Do not try to put that file under version control. Nobody MUST NOT has right and ability to change that file. Other wise they may bypass restriction implemented by that hook.

Comment: @Rekha: [here](https://varrunr.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/scp-copy-fromto-remote-server-with-ssh/) is it

Comment: @ Eugen Konkov Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please keep in mind that not all the git repositories support SSH connection, for example GitHub does not do and it has its own tools to achieve the same behaviour.