Server-side hook on GitHub
I need to prevent secrets from being pushed to my repository, so I’m implementing Git hooks. While client-side hooks are working correctly, they require each user to configure their local .git directory using the command:
git config core.hooksPath .githooks
This dependency on individual user configuration is a limitation, which is why I’d like to switch to a server-side solution.
In the Git documentation, server-side hooks like pre-receive are mentioned as a potential solution. However, I couldn’t find clear instructions on how to implement them on GitHub. Is it possible to implement a server-side hook directly on GitHub? If so, how can this be done?
referance:https://git-scm.com/book/ms/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
i have implented client-side already

This question is similar to: github server-side git hooks (i.e. pre-commit and post-commit). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505459/how-to-setup-server-side-pre-receive-hook, it also looks informative.
